# Stopping Couchbase Elasticsearch XDCR OutOfMemory Error

Tags: elasticsearch, out-of-memory, couchbase

I am running a proof of concept on a VM with 4Gb Ram.  I have around 2 million docs in Couchbase and want to get them all into Elasticsearch using the XDCR plugin however Couchbase pushes ES too hard and ES falls over.  I don't have much room left to increase the memory past the 1Gb default, is there a way to slow the replication down to give ES room to breath?

**Edit:**

I should add some history here.  I used to have this working, ES was indexing the Couchbase docs pretty damn fast but then I ran out of disk space on my VM.  I added a new disk and changed the path.data property in elasticsearch.yml.  After that I couldn't start ES using the init.d script provided in the deb.  It says ES started ok but then if I run /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status it says, "Elasticsearch server is not running but pid file exists".  I re-installed ES just for the hell of it but nothing.  I can't work out how I can find out what is failing when I run the init script.  I can however start ES perfectly well manually and if couchbase isn't running everything is cool.  I'm not sure if this is relevant at all but at some point I need to get that working too.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to modify `couchbase.maxConcurrentRequests: 1024` to a lower number in elasticsearch.yml?
Perhaps simply set it to 256 could work?

Comment: So, I've played around with maxConcurrentRequests and even taken it down to 8 with no luck.  I've increased heap size from the default 1Gb to 2Gb but when I look at top, as ES starts up it slowly increases mem to it's usual 170Mb or so and then after a few seconds you can see it must start talking to couchbase and the memory usage shoots up to the limit, so when I increased heap size from 1Gb to 2Gb, instead of shooting up to 1.1g it went to 2.1g.  The command I'm running is: sudo ./elasticsearch -f -Des.path.data=/data -Des.couchbase.password=password -Des.couchbase.maxConcurrentRequests=8